# What is the correct way to enable a setting in each scenario

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

We have a setting to enable the tracking of viewed objects, but this has to be turned on. So I was thinking to put this in a Background. However, there's one Scenario which should warn the user when that option isn't enabled yet and the button to show viewed objects is clicked. What is the best way to tackle this?

**Option 1: Use a Background, but as far as I can see, there's no way to have it not fire when in a Scenario.**

```
Background: Turn on tracking of objects
Given the user is on the settings page
When tracking is enabled
Then the user should see tracking is enabled
```

**Option 2: Use something like this starting each scenario:**

```
Given ...
And tracking of viewed objects is on
When ...
Then ...
```

I'm not opposed to doing that, but all that repetition makes me think there's a better way of doing this.

**Option 3: Put the one Scenario in a different feature file.**

I would preferably put everything concerning tracking in one file, but if this is best practice ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on a recent version of Cucumber you can use [the `Rule` keyword](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/). Rules allow you to group scenarios/example in a feature file. Each rule can have it's own background.

```
Feature: Overdue tasks
  Let users know when tasks are overdue, even when using other
  features of the app

  Rule: Users are notified about overdue tasks on first use of the day
    Background:
      Given I have overdue tasks

    Example: First use of the day
      Given I last used the app yesterday
      When I use the app
      Then I am notified about overdue tasks

    Example: Already used today
      Given I last used the app earlier today
      When I use the app
      Then I am not notified about overdue tasks
  ...
```

Note: that rules work best when used in combination with [Example Mapping](https://cucumber.io/blog/bdd/example-mapping-introduction/). If you only use them to group your features because you need a shared background it may get messy.

Comment: Thank you. I also appreciated the link to Example Mapping.